# Ho to run multiple mobile tests on Sauce Labs via Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, webdriver-io, saucelabs, jira-xray

I have a problem with run Jenkins job with additional parameters
In my package.json I named a script name with some browser configs like:

```
 "mobile": "npx wdio run ./config/wdio.mobile.conf.js"
```

I have got a config file with my mobile devices:

```
exports.config = {
    ...config,
    ...{
        user: process.env.SAUCE_USERNAME,
        key: process.env.SAUCE_ACCESS_KEY,
        testobject_api_key: process.env.SAUCE_RDC_ACCESS_KEY,
        region: 'eu',
        specs: [
            './features/*'
        ],
        maxInstances: 1,
        capabilities: [{
            deviceName: 'Samsung Galaxy S',
            automationName: 'UiAutomator2',
            platformName: 'Android',
            idleTimeout: 180,
            cacheId: new Date().getTime(),
            noReset: true,
            autoGrantPermissions: true,
            orientation: 'PORTRAIT',
            newCommandTimeout: 180,
            build: 'test',
            name: 'test',
            maxInstances: 1,
        }],
        services: ['sauce'],
    }
}
```

But instead of hardcoded strings with deviceName etc I want to use some parameters to set any device while running Jenkins job something like:

[image: Jenkins job configuration]

Additional problem:

How to manage running multiple devices? For example an array of devices at once. (30 devices).

I would appreciate your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do that is to manipulate env file

On Jenkins side:

- creation of Jenkins input with devices
- with every run with chosen device add dynamically new node variable to env file with deviceName, automationName and platformName:

> ```
> echo DEVICE_NAME=${DEVICE_NAME} >> .env
> ```

On config side parametrize device capabilities like that:

```
deviceName: `${process.env.DEVICE_NAME}`
automationName: `${process.env.AUTOMATION_NAME}`
platformName: `${process.env.PLATFORM_NAME}`
```